# CSS - Header elements not floating properly when re-sizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently adding all media queries to a site and I'm stuck with some of the header elements that refuse to float properly when I resize below `480px` to mobile-wide. I want my Logo to stretch across the page and all the other elements to float on top of each other. At the moment the phone/email are side by side and social media icons are stuck on the left and won't display inline across the page. I've tried all variants of `display` rules but they won't budge.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Merriweather Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #333333;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

header {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.left-header {
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}

.right-header {
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
}

.right-header-top {
  background: white;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.right-header-bottom {
  background: white;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
}

nav a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

div#contact {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

div#contact img {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

div#contact p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.right-header-bottom i {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  div.container {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  }
  div.column {
    float: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  header {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  nav a {
    display: block;
  }
  .right-header {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
  .right-header-top {
    float: none;
  }
  .right-header-bottom {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<header>
  <div class="left-header">
    <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo" style="width:250px;height:30px;">
  </div>
  <div class="right-header">
    <div class="right-header-top">
      <div id="contact">
        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/phone.png">
        <p>0113 220 5265</p>
        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/email.png">
        <p>hello@featuremedia.co.uk</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-header-bottom">
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
        <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
        <a href="business.html">PRODUCTS</a>
        <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
      </nav>

      <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here's how it looks -

[image: Mobile-wide RWD]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a lot of `float`s to kill.

A few things to display `block` and some text to align enter.

```css
body {
 font-family: "Merriweather Sans", sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.5;
 color: #333333;
}


body {
  
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


header {
 background: #ffffff;
 height: 100px;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 10;
}


.left-header { background:white; width:50%; float:left; height: 100px; }


.right-header { background:white; width:50%; float:right; height: 50px;  }

.right-header-top { background: white; float: right; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-right: 100px; }

.right-header-bottom  { background: white; float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

#logo {

 margin-left: 60px;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

nav {
 float: left;
 font-weight: 400;
}

nav a {
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-right:  25px;
 font-size: 12px;
 
}

div#contact {
 
 float: right;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

div#contact img {
 display: inline-block;
 
 border: 10px;
 margin: 20px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;

}

div#contact p {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 25px;
 
 
 font-size: 10px;
}


.right-header-bottom i {
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 border: 15px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

a {
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 color: #000000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  div.container {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  }

  div.column {
    float: none;
   
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 


  header {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
   
  }

  nav {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  nav a {
    display: block;
    
  } 

  .right-header {
    
   height: auto;
    width: auto;
  }

  .right-header-top {
    float: none;
  }

  .right-header-bottom {
    float: none; 
  }
  
}
  
/* Added Styles */
  
.left-header {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img#logo {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto !important;
}

.right-header {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div[class*="header"] {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

div#contact {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    height: auto;
}

body {
    max-width: 500px;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    min-height: 400px;
}

nav {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.right-header-bottom i {
    float: none;
}

/* Centered Nav, Email & Phone */

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

div#contact
 > div img {
    margin: auto;
}

div#contact
 > div p {
    margin: auto 10px;
    line-height: 3em;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div#contact
 > div:first-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

nav.block a {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  
<header>
        <div class="left-header">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/500x100" alt="logo" id="logo" style="width:250px;height:30px;">
        </div>
    <div class="right-header">
         <div class="right-header-top">
            <div id="contact">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
                <p>0113 220 5265</p>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
                <p>hello@featuremedia.co.uk</p>
            </div>    
         </div>
         <div class="right-header-bottom">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                <a href="business.html">PRODUCTS</a>
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>


            </nav>

                <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </div>
    </div>
 </header>
  
</body>

<h1>Center Nav, Email & Phone</h1>

<head>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  
<header>
        <div class="left-header">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/500x100" alt="logo" id="logo">
        </div>
    <div class="right-header">
         <div class="right-header-top">
            <div id="contact">
                <div>
                  <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
                  <p>0113 220 5265</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
                  <p>hello@featuremedia.co.uk</p>
                </div>
            </div>    
         </div>
         <div class="right-header-bottom">
            <nav class="block">
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                <a href="business.html">PRODUCTS</a>
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>


            </nav>

                <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </div>
    </div>
 </header>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think I'm sinking with all my floats? You're solution is pretty good, although my nav & icons aren't quite central like yours are. I need to have a look through again and see if I have any extra padding or something.

Comment: At those viewports you are. Most floats at mobile screen sizes only serve to align small content effectively (icons usually still work well with floats), but most other elements can just be displayed `block` - all very circumstantial, but as a general rule of thumb, you can usually get by with the "block and center" DOM-flow. `flex` is another great solution that has the browser doing all the calculations for you with dynamic element resizing, but because it's still a bit gimmicky in older browsers I tend to avoid it for most production code and stick with tired and trusted methods.

Comment: heh "tired and trusted."  nice mental slip there :)

Comment: @McHat Yep, got me there - I should've proof-read it a third time

Answer (score 0):

get rid of `float: right` on `div#contact` and change `display: inline-block` to `display: block` on `nav a`

-OR-

Use this CSS for your nav:

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav a {
  align-self: center;
}
```

And you still have to kill the float on the header.

Here is a useful fiddle I keep in my bookmarks for flexbox reference.  It shows everything flexbox can do and makes it relatively easy to understand:
https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv

Comment: I second the suggestion below to use CSS 3 flexbox.  CSS is a pesky little beast to learn and flex makes many things easier and more intuitive.

Comment: How do I use it effectively here, though?